# Multilingual apps issue

Tags: java, android

First of all, i met some problem in my LanguageActivity.java .Lets say if i pick "zh" from my spinner, it supposed to change the strings.xml to "zh".But i found that some string in my interface doesn't change to the [zh]strings.xml.

[image: Settings Does not change to chinese]

Here is my code of LanguageActivity.java

```
             @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_language);
    spinnerctrl = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinnerctrl.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {

            if (pos == 1) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("en");
            } else if (pos == 2) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("zh");
            } else if (pos == 3) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected Hindi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("hi");
            }
            else if (pos == 4) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected Malay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("ms");
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to select", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}

public void setLocale(String lang) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    if (!conf.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
        conf.locale = new Locale(lang);
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, LanguageActivity.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the `Locale` changes you have to restart your app.

Try this:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
             .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Put it after the setLocale method?

Comment: Yes. It will restart the app applying the `Locale` changes

Comment: @Nicholas Cortell Pardon, you mean like this?

Comment: if (!conf.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
            conf.locale = new Locale(lang);
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, LanguageActivity.class);
            startActivity(refresh);

        }
        Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }

Comment: Thanks nicholas it work.. but i don't know why still have some string doesn't change...

Comment: Probably because some of the strings are not in all the folders.

Comment: I have check the strings, it is inside my strings.xml. First, it is "en" version of system. After i change it to "zh" version，it works fine. But the problem came after i change to another language,some strings still remain at "zh", no matter how many times i change the language, the "zh"version of some strings still remain after i change to another language. Do you get what i mean?

Comment: Check if you find those strings in your "zh" folder

Comment: I can confirmed all these string i also have translated in another strings file too. I don't know it is my coding problem or what. After second change, the first change of some string remain at second change.Third change the string still remain at first change.

Comment: For example , en-> zh, zh->hi (some zh string doesnt change in hi version), hi->ms（ zh string still remain at ms version).

Comment: Lol , i dont know what is this code...lblLang.setText(R.string.langselection);

Answer (score 1):

Instead of restarting app, You may also update configuration:

```
String languageCode="en";
Resources res = getResources();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale(languageCode);
res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing code investigation, my string code is title name. I need to set the code like this "setTitle(R.string.setting);". So my title string only able to change, thanks for helping me all my friends :)